# What type of power cord do I need for my external hard drive?

Tags: external-hard-drive, lacie

I have an external hard drive and I've lost all of its cords.  I'm not sure what I should get.  I don't want to get the wrong voltage and ruin it.

This is the drive (but mine is 1TB, I think, don't remember): [http://www.amazon.com/dp/B0010YWPZ8?tag=evo43-20](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0010YWPZ8)

Answer (score 0):

You need to flip it over and look for a combination of voltage and current (amps), and wheter it's alternating or direct current (VAC / VDC)

It will read something like "12v @ 115 ma".

Your replacement should match on the voltage, and have AT LEAST the same number of amps/milliamps in rating.  And the current type must match (VAC/VDC)

Obviously the end connector must be the same, and for DC the polarity matters (which contact is positive or negative).